# OpenGL what does setting the texture uniform handle do?

Tags: opengl-es

so I have some code:

```
mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_Texture");
```

that gets the handle for `u_texture` and does something with it in the fragment shader.

```
 final String perPixelFragmentShader =
        "precision mediump float;                   \n" +
        "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;               \n" +
        "varying vec3 v_Position;                   \n" +
        "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;              \n" +
                "void main() {                      \n" +
                "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate); }    \n";
```

However, I'm confused as to what this following line does:

```
GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);
```

I thought this line was equivalent to

```
uniform sampler2d u_Texture = 0;
```

But if that's the case, I don't think `texture2d(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate)` would work correctly. a 2d Texture according to the enums listed should be:

```
public static final int GL_TEXTURE_2D = 3553;
```

So I'm really confused as to why I'm setting the handle to 0 using the `glUniform1i()` call.

Comment: A very similar question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901397/activating-using-gl-texture1-at-opengl-es-2-0-for-android

Answer (score 0):

The value you assign to the `uniform sampler2D` is based on which of the bound textures you want to use it for, not what kinds of texture it is.

Judging by the variable names your code is based on http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-four-introducing-basic-texturing/. If you look at the section *Using the texture* you see an explanation. Quote:

> In short:
>
> 1. Set the active texture unit.
> 2. Bind a texture to this unit.
> 3. Assign this unit to a texture uniform in the fragment shader.
>
> Repeat for as many textures as you need.

Your question is about step 3, and the number you use is based on step 1 (which you don't include), in your example texture unit `0`.

This is one the strange parts of OpenGL Shaders. There is not really a strong need to make it this complicated (it would be nice to be able to just say `uniform sampler2d u_Texture = 0;` and be done with it), but unfortunately it doesn't work that way.