# Activating/using GL_TEXTURE1 at OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to use the GL_TEXTURE1 texture unit to draw a simple shape. I know how to draw it using the standard GL_TEXTURE0, but when changing it something is not working.

I thought that from my code below, I just had to change the following:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glUniform1i(uTextureLocation, 1);
```

What I'm missing?

Code:

```
public class RendererClass implements Renderer {

Context context;

FloatBuffer verticesInBuffer;

int aPositionLocation;
int aTextureLocation;
int uTextureLocation;

int program;

public RendererClass(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig config) {

    GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    float[] vertices = {

            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
            -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
             0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
             0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f  

    };

    verticesInBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer().put(vertices);

    String vss = "attribute vec4 a_Position;" +
                 "attribute vec2 a_Texture;" +
                 "varying vec2 v_Texture;" +
                 "void main(){" +
                 "    v_Texture = a_Texture;" +
                 "    gl_Position = a_Position;" +
                 "}";

    String fss = "precision mediump float;" +
                 "varying vec2 v_Texture;" +
                 "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;" +
                 "void main(){" +
                 "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_Texture);" +
                 "}";

    int vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vs, vss);
    glShaderSource(fs, fss);

    glCompileShader(vs);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    program = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);

    glLinkProgram(program);

    aPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, "a_Position");


    // ***** Texture stuff starts here   </</</</


    // Fase 1
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    int[] genTextures = new int[1];
    glGenTextures(1, genTextures, 0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, genTextures[0]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);


    // Fase 2
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;

    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.res_for_test_1, options);


    // Fase 3
    texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap1, 0);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    


    // Fase 4
    aTextureLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, "a_Texture");
    uTextureLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "u_Texture");

    glUniform1i(uTextureLocation, 0);

    verticesInBuffer.position(2);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(aTextureLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(aTextureLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 16, verticesInBuffer);


 // ***** Texture stuff ends here   </</</</


}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 arg0, int width, int height) {

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(program);

    verticesInBuffer.position(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 16, verticesInBuffer);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);

}

}
```

Comment: Did you try to bind the texture after you activate the texture unit?
If you bind the texture before the Activate operation the texture is bound to the texture unit 0.

Comment: Yes. If you look at the code first I call "glActivateTexture" and then "glBindTexture". Any other clue?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm stuck on the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify active texture unit and assign a previously loaded texture to it.

For convenience, I've created a helper function which does all of this. It activates given texture unit, assigns texture with given ID to it and puts this value to `sampler2D` uniform of shader:

```
protected void setTexture2D(int textureUnit, int textureID, int uniformID) {
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 + textureUnit);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(uniformID, textureUnit);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
setTexture2D(0, textureID, uniformID);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but how is that different from my code? I first call "glActiveTexture" then "glBindTexture" and then "glUniform1i". The same your helper function works. It's not working for GL_TEXTURE1.